# How to fix VB6 APPCRASH ntdll.dll error on make

Tags: windows, vb6, windows-xp, windows-7-x64

I am making an exe from an existing VB6 project. During Make, VB crashes with the following message

```
Visual Basic has stopped working

Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name: vb6.exe
Application Version: 6.0.97.82
Fault Module Name: ntdll.dll
```

Exception Code: `c0000005`

I am able to run the project from VB6 without any trouble. The problem occurs when I try to make the exe.

Please could you let me know what could be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Are there any Add-ins installed? Does the failure happen when using the IDE, the command line, or both? Do you have SP6 installed?

Comment: @Peter Cooper Jr. There is True DBGrid Pro 6.0 add-in apart from source code control and component services add-in. Build error occurs in both IDE and command line. SP6 is installed already.

Comment: That means *Invalid access to memory location.* This is a programming error in VB6 not of your making so you can't fix it. Generally caused by system configuration not anticipated. Reinstall, install SP6, run as administrator (if you aren't). Make sure source files are ok (in notepad check them). Also do you have the fault address.

Comment: Thanks for getting back @CatCat. I could build other projects fine. It is just one of the projects that throws this error. Could it be a bug in this project? I have tried running the IDE as administrator and in compatibility mode with XP which didn't solve the problem.

Comment: As I said vb6.exe is encountering unexpected something. Check all files. Text files you can use notepad. Frx and vbw (they are binary) files try to recreate.

Comment: Also do you have the crash address.

Comment: Hi @CatCat, the address is 0x000000007c911780 Code: 0xc0000005 Flags:0x00000000 Record: 0x0000000000000000

Comment: @najarajar Have you tried changing [compiler settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa240843%28v%3dvs.60%29)? Switching to P-Code or Native Code, changing which optimizations are on, that kind of thing?

Comment: Yes @PeterCooperJr. Tried those without any success.

Comment: I would edit all these additional debugging details (crash address etc.) directly into the question

Answer (score 0):

This all needs to be done on the computer with the fault. I cannot load my `ntdll.dll` as it a different version and the addresses will be different to yours.

Download and install Debugging Tools for Windows

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363

Install the Windows SDK but just choose the debugging tools.

Create a folder called `Symbols` in `C:\`

This allows WinDbg to get the symbols for your version of ntdll.dll. Start Windbg. *File* menu - *Symbol File Path* and enter

```
srv*C:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

then

Open ntdll in WinDbg as a **crashdump**.

It will show the load address.

Type in WinDbg

```
ln <modloadaddress> + 7c911780
```

This will give you the nearest symbol to the crash. It probably isn't useful but lets see.

---

You can also run VB6 under WinDbg (make sure WinDbg is run as admin). When you crash do a stack trace.

Also do an `!Analyze` when you crash. It is meant for blue screens but will give info on appcrash.

Type in the WinDbg command prompt

```
!analyze -v
```

`-v` stands for Verbose and if the crash was originated by a program, as opposed to hardware or a driver, it will appear in the middle of the listing.

eg

PROCESS_NAME:  java.exe
IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe

PROCESS_NAME only appears in the `analyze -v` output and only if a program originated the call that faulted.

**WinDbg Commands**

Open as **Executable**.

windbg -o -g -G c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /k batfile.bat

You can press `F12` to stop it and `kb` will show the call stack (`g` continues the program). If there's errors it will also stop and show them.

There is a breakpoint after loading but before any code is run. Press `g` to continue. Likewise there is a breakpoint after all code has run but before it is unloaded.

Type `lm` to list loaded modules, `x *!*` to list the symbols and `bp symbolname` to set a breakpoint

If programming in VB6 then this environmental variable `link=/pdb:none` stores the symbols in the dll rather than separate files. Make sure you compile the program with *No Optimisations* and tick the box for *Create Symbolic Debug Info*. Both on the Compile tab in the Project's Properties.

**Sample** output from a nearest symbol search.

> Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll] Symbol search path
>
> is: srv*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
>
> Executable search path is:  **ModLoad: 4b280000** 4b3f9000
>
> C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000000
>
> edx=00000000 esi=00000000 edi=00000000 eip=4b280000 esp=00000000
>
> ebp=00000000 iopl=0         nv up di pl nz na pe nc cs=0000  ss=0000
>
> ds=0000  es=0000  fs=0000  gs=0000             efl=00000000
>
> ntdll!__guard_fids_table  (ntdll+0x0): 4b280000 4d
>
> dec     ebp 0:000> **ln 4b280000 + 65534** (4b2e5520)
>
> **ntdll!RtlInitializeBitMap+0x14   |  (4b2e5540)**
>
> **ntdll!TpCallbackUnloadDllOnCompletion**

**Sample** stack trace.

You follow what function called what functions. So you read it from the bottom up. It has the first 4 parameters that were passed to the function. You find the debugger starts additional threads so we need to find our program's one.

```
~
```

Lists all threads

```
~<threadid> e <command>
```

Do a KB on all threads until you find the main one.

> 0:004> **~0 e kb**
>
> ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child               04bdfc30
>
> 75ae325a 04bdfc70 00000000 00000000 USER32!NtUserGetMessage+0xc
>
> 04bdfc4c 00895eb6 **04bdfc70** 00000000 00000000 USER32!GetMessageW+0x2a
>
> 04bdfc8c 008a5b41 00890000 00000000 04e2336f notepad!WinMain+0xe6
>
> 04bdfd20 74ad3744 7f229000 74ad3720 10fde46e
>
> notepad!WinMainCRTStartup+0x151 04bdfd34 7755a064 7f229000 b0c1107f
>
> 00000000 KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24 04bdfd7c 7755a02f ffffffff
>
> 7757d7c9 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f 04bdfd8c 00000000
>
> 008a59f0 7f229000 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

Assume that **04bdfc70** is an HWnd. Which it is because the documentation says so. But assume it an address of a string. This displays what is there.

```
ds 775a1300
```

or to look at the values

```
db 775a1300
```