# How to generate a heap corruption from VB6

Tags: vb6, windows-services, heap-corruption

We have a C# windows service that call vb6 functions and one of our customer has sometime this service that crashed with  0xc0000374 error on ntdll.dll (Heap Corruption Exception).

It's impossible for us to reproduce their problem, and in order to learn how windbg works and how debug this exception, how can I generate the same error with a piece of VB6 code ?

It would allow me to see how could I debug this kind of error and make the same things at my client site.

Thank you for your help

Comment: If you're trying to create a learning experience with windbg, no need to recreate the same error.  Just creating some sort of unhandled exception will probably address your needs. Perhaps a divide by zero?  Or a custom `err.raise`?

Comment: Your idea is worthless (unless it's just for learning about windbg). Get the crash data from the customer, and analyse that. `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Security and Maintenance\Problem Details` and their will be a crash dump for recent crashes (the crash dumps themselves get deleted after a while leaving just the error message). Also see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53636777/how-to-fix-vb6-appcrash-ntdll-dll-error-on-make

Comment: Also use Remote Assistance to run vb6/windbg on the customers computer. Install VB6 and WinDbg on customers computer. Then type remote assistance in Control Panal search. This feature has been in windows since Windows 95 - everyone seems to have forgotten about it.